# People picker on different web apps behaves differently

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, people-picker

We have migrated 2007 MOSS applications to SP 2013. We have two web applications on our SharePoint 2013 Farm. Consider SC1 is Site collection on webapp1 and SC2 is on Web App 2. When we try to search for an user in people/group column using browse option, in SC1 we see more results than in SC2. Are we missing on something?